# 'Open In' functionality after downloading document?

Tags: cocoa-touch, documents

I am developing an iOS app that allows users to download documents off a server. I have gotten this to work fine and they can even view the document. What I want, though, is for the document to have an 'Open In' action so, when a button is pressed, the user is able to select another application that allows you to look at PDF documents -- for example, the Kindle App. Is this possible?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it is ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darn, I was wishing you were going to say "MacOS" because that would have made the answer a lot more fun (and do-able).

As far as I know, iOS still does not have an official SDK-legal way to have one app (your app) arbitrarily launch other app and specify an arbitrary document to open with it. This is part of the magic (?) of having to live within your own app sandbox.

On the Macintosh, this would be easy with Apple Events (among other things).

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  If you're a registered Apple developer, you can file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com and request for them to add this functionality in future iOS releases.  The more developers who request it, the more likely it is that it'll be positively considered.